# No Bootable Device

Tags: hard-drive, acer-aspire

When starting up my Acer Aspire 3, I receive a message stating 'No Bootable Device'. I have accessed the BIOS menu, reset the defaults, and tried restarting. Nothing seems to be working.
I believe this issue is a result of static electricity affecting the hard drive. The laptop started up fine after the static electricity incident, then froze so I shut down. Upon starting up again, I received the 'No Bootable Device' message.
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

A little more information:
Acer Aspire 3 A315-21-95KF
AMD Dual-Core Processor A9-9420
6 GB DDR4 Memory

Recovering data isn't an issue, I had everything important backed up before this issue started.

Comment: Is there a disk in the CD/DVD drive or a USB thumb drive attached? If so, remove them and try again.

Comment: I don't have a CD/DVD drive but I did have a USB connect for a wireless mouse. I removed it, went through the BIOS screen again to reset defaults but nothing changed. I'm still receiving the 'No Bootable Device' screen.

Comment: what OS? does the device support `secure boot` and is `secure boot` enabled? have you tried `legacy boot`?

Comment: Is your harddrive detected by the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I would replace the hard drive. From what you have described, the existing drive may be damaged and this is usually the quickest and cheapest way to both find out and simultaneously fix.

Answer (score 0):

A hard drive is a mechanical device, and it has a high probability of failure over time. A magnetic disk will be rotating inside it(moving part), and there is HEAD (moving part) reading and writing data.

This is why they configure RAID in highly reliable systems. So most probably you should replace the HDD :(

SSD's will have less probability of failure as it doesn't have any moving parts. But it's a little costlier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting into the command line editor? Try running a cmd.exe ver6.3 or higher.If you do get into the command line screen type diskpart/type list disk /if your hard drive is still alive it will be listed as disk 0 or disk.../? the list disk command shows only the disks and some info as file type ect. If not try list volumes and check the volumes too.read up before running the diskpart. command in the cmd.exe enviroment.It can save you some headache.I suggest reading command line cmdslets.
.You can create a boot pen drive with cmd.exe on it and boot into cmd mode.Rufus.com has a free boot tool for creating USB boot drives use it carefully. Goodluck.